# ubuntu does no let me log in to my user, how can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu

My ubuntu has just crashed. Now that I restarted it, it does nothing when I enter my password. The screen just gets refreshed leaving the password space empty again. However, if I try to enter a wrong password, it recognize that it is an invalid password. There is also a weird white box around the user names and password in the ubuntu log in page.

A worth mentioning point is that while I was using Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart the computer the window that asks whether I want to restart or shut down the computer was not able to show the characters, there were blank squares instead of each character.

I have tried to set a new password for my user by logging into recovery shell, but it did not work! I also created a new user but couldn't log in to that neither:(

Any suggestion how I can fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell using your username and your password. In this case username will be your username you set when you installed Ubuntu.

Now run `ls -lah`. If in the output the line(and look for the line that ends with .Xauthority)

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in.

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

*Make sure you are connected to internet with DHCP on.*

1. `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
4. `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Now type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart.

Comment: What helped me is to do the same change to .ICEauthority as one for .Xauthority. That is, 
chown username:username .ICEauthority

Comment: And what do I do if nothing of these are working? I am trying to install Ubuntu on a separate SSD

Comment: @Pavlos try chat or IRC channel

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds Thank you! I formatted my disk and install Windows and then Ubuntu to fix it!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20, this basic process worked but with `gdm3` instead of `lightdm`.