# Linux Mint doesn't boot - I accidently sent user folder to /usr/local/sbin

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I accidently sent the user folder to /usr/local/sbin, trying to move a script file from the user to the sbin folder.

When I send the script, I did not run it or anything, I just sent it with

```
sudo mv
```

Suddenly, I couldn't open any folder in desktop in GUI, and

> This folder may not exist or it was deleted

was shown to me. I opened the terminal and it was changed: I was in the terminal as root.

I restarted my pc, and every time I inserted my password, the screen just refreshed and nothing was happening, and I was asked again and again to insert my pass.

I found this thread [ubuntu does no let me log in to my user, how can I fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170650/ubuntu-does-no-let-me-log-in-to-my-user-how-can-i-fix-it) and I tried to solve the problem by installing lightdm, but before doing that, I changed again the permissions in root, since I thought that was the problem, with `sudo chmod u-w root`. (I changed the permissions for a different reason, this morning)

I typed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

But I forgot the next command, which was

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

So I restarted my pc to go to windows to see the command again. Then I restarted again, to boot Linux, and I couldn't: the mint logo was just refreshing and refreshing. I tried to go in recovery mode to run as root the

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

command. I did, but after restarting again, nothing was solver. The mint logo was refreshing again. So now I can't even go to the login page.

EDIT: I managed to move the user folder back to home, in the recovery mode, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify - this is a dual-boot with Windows? How far into the Mint boot sequence do you get? Can you get to a command line?

Comment: Hey. It is a dual-boot with Windows. I can get to a command line, with recovery mode. That is how I managed to move back the user folder to home from usr/local/sbin.

Comment: Ok. I don't know why you wouldn't be able to get to the lightdm login screen. Perhaps check the folder permissions for the `/home` directory are still set correctly?

Comment: I checked the permissions, but everything was fine