# Can't log into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, login, gpg

Today I booted up Ubuntu and the login screen was back to the default for some reason and every time I tried to log in it would show a black screen and return me back to the login screen. I have tried the suggestions from [ubuntu does no let me log in to my user, how can I fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170650/ubuntu-does-no-let-me-log-in-to-my-user-how-can-i-fix-it) and that didn't help.

I did find that when I tried to update I got this error:

```
W: GPG error: HTTP://cdn.dyn.com/dynupdater/debian stable/ Release: The 
following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C0943F422A34BCA6 Dyn Package 
Signing Key
```

I also get an error that that repository is not signed. From there I tried the suggestions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig

Importing the key still says that it is expired. I'm not familiar with keys and this sort of thing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit more elaborate than your link above:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/

[ubuntu does no let me log in to my user, how can I fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170650/ubuntu-does-no-let-me-log-in-to-my-user-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you that is a better source but unfortunately it didn't end up solving anything.